# AngularJS $stateProvider URL results in blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I'm using angular-ui-router and set up a 2nd controller similar to my 1st one which was working, but the route in the 2nd controller is not properly routing the app. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

html for first controller (works properly):

```
<div style="height: 100%"> <!--took out: ng-if="map.center !== undefined"-->
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_g7xCYEi-U54SYfTXQ_lukRsChkWgjXQ'></script>
</div>
```

1st controller (works properly ):

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) { //had: , $stateChangeError included in the function parameters, but that caused error 
      $stateProvider.state('searchRadius', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'searchRadius.html', //changed from  index to searchRadius.html
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',
      });
  })


    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
          alert(JSON.stringify(center));
          Object.freeze(center); //caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

          console.log($stateParams);

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }

          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function(){
                $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
          }, 1000); //end of interval function


      } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

2nd html (blank page):

```
<!--Add ability to input location as address-->

<div>
        <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWKJRXSux3dAdEYOYqjkoi2MCW8dutFbY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</div>
```

2nd controller (results in blank page with no errors):

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) { //had: , $stateChangeError included in the function parameters, but that caused error 
      $stateProvider.state('getLocation', {
          url: '/getLocation',
          templateUrl: 'getlocation.html', //changed from  index to searchRadius.html
          controller: 'GetlocationCtrl',
      });
  })



    .controller('GetlocationCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = { latitude: 49.22, longitude: -122.66 }; //default center
          alert(JSON.stringify(center));

          console.log($stateParams);

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }


      } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

Comment: are you trying to declare the module twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) You are using $`routerProvider` which is not necessarily required

(ii) Also when i check your code, you are loading the first module after loading the 2nd controller. Place your scripts like this  in index.html ,

```
<script src="searchRadius.js"></script> 
<script src="getLoc.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made that change but the page still came up blank and I also go an 'app is not available...make sure you have the dependencies...' error

Comment: @Thomas can you give team viewer?

Comment: what's team viewer? Do you mean like jsfiddle or something? And if it works here is the url to the page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2#/getLocation

Comment: I don't have that and i don't really want to use it i might play around with it later though, thanks.

Comment: i checked your code still you have not removed the module on the second controlelr, also you are using $routerProvider which is not necessarily required

Comment: I changed it back because it gave me the error. But I just changed it back again in case you want to see the error

Comment: place   <script src="searchRadius.js"></script> ahead of the   <script src="getLoc.js"></script> in index.html and let me know

Comment: After doing that, keeping the dependencies in the 2nd controller definition and removing urlRouteProvider like you suggested it works! Thank you. If you modify your answer I will accept it so others can see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125218/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-thomas).